# Sound Baking in Blender

Tags: python, visualization, blender

Hi I am working on a project in blender with the 'sound_bake' function. I have formatted it as the console is telling me but am still receiving an error. Please help! Here is an excerpt from the code(everything works fine until I add the 4th line of this excerpt.) Thank You.

```
cubeobject = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location = (r*2,c*2,0))  

bpy.ops.transform.resize(value = (1,1,10))
bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type = 'Scaling')
bpy.ops.graph.sound_bake(filepath=r"C:\Users\Tyler\Music\Enter Shikari\12-enter_shikari-sorry_youre_not_a_winner.mp3")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please clarify what the error is? "still receiving an error" is not very descriptive. Please take a moment to read through [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You can always [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

Found out the answer shortly after posting. Blender is weird and you have to change the text window in which you are writing the code in into a 'Graph Editor' window. You have to do this by writing the code into your program within the text editor. It is only one line but I believe it does need to be before the sound_bake function is called. Here is the line of code:

bpy.context.area.type = 'GRAPH_EDITOR'

...and remember to place it BEFORE the sound_bake function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Some other issues with your code are:

1) The `primitive_cube_add` function does not return the created cube, but just something like "finished". Afterwards the new cube is the active object, so you can do this:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location = (r*2,c*2,0))
cubeobject = bpy.context.active_object
```

The second line seems equivalent to

```
cubeobject = bpy.context.object
```

I don't know (yet) what the difference is.

2) `bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu()` is some function to add a `keyframe` using a menu. Which is silly when used from a script. `bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert()` seems a little more appropriate. This still can not run from a startup script, only from within the gui. Better is:

```
cubeobject.keyframe_insert('scale')
```

Unfortunately this is where I'm currently at with a similar project.
I'm stuck at trying to get `bpy.ops.graph.sound_bake` work from a script. 
Setting the context to graph editor only works when run from the GUI. When run from the command line, `bpy.context.area` is undefined.